# Saving a variable in HTML so that the user only has to enter the information one time

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-applications

So if I'm on the login page of my website, I type "Joe Bob" and "111" in the 'Name' and 'MNo' fields, made with with this code:

```
<form action="userLogin.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
Member Number: <input type="text" name="MNo"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value = "Sign in!">
</form>
```

On the next page I can take the name and member ID from the inputted field like this:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$MNo = $_POST["MNo"];
```

---

Now on that same page I want to have a button that Joe Bob can click that will display his user's history: I'll need his MNo to search the MySQL database, but when I go to the next page, using

```
<form action = "rentalHistory.php" method = "get">
 <input type="submit" value="View my Rental History"> 
</form>
```

I'm no longer allowed to use

```
$MNo = $_POST["MNo"];
```

The error says *"Notice: Undefined index: MNo"*, which means it is not saving the MNo variable from the previous page: how do I do this?

As you saw, it worked when I had the user input their member number, but I don't want to have to do this every time.

How do I make it so that the user enters the member number at the beginning, and then it can be used for MySQL queries on multiple pages after login?

Comment: Since you want to use these values on other page so put it in session or cookie and then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of having data follow a user around in php, the foremost I would recommend is using [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) then assigning values to the session variables.

Another way, but one that I would not recommend is to have the user continue to the next page via a form with hidden attributes `<input type="hidden name="MNo" value="value">`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="rentalHistory.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="MNo" value="$_POST[MNo]">
   <input type="submit" value="View my Rental History">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When a `$_POST` variable is not available after a page load, that means that you have either posted a form that does not contain the variable with the name in it, or that you have done a `GET` request which will pass the user's name as a query string (This will still not work if no name input, hidden or otherwise, was included in the form).

Try `$_GET['name']` first, if that does not work, you need to add to your rental history lookup form a hidden input with the name of `name` and make the value of it the previously posted `$_POST['name']` value.

You can also store user data in the session if you need to access it often, make sure to destroy sessions when applicable!

Comment: like this? 

   <form action="rentalHistory.php" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="MNo" value="$_POST["MNo"]">
   <input type="submit" value="View my Rental History">
   </form>



The variable just becomes: $_POST[ when I try to print it, when it should be printing 1111